# Why some buttons look different in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a crud application in React.
As you can see from the picture, some buttons look different somehow I don't know why.
Could you please help me with finding the error, I can't find it and have spent hours on it.
As you can see from the picture, "Güncelle" and "Sil" buttons don't look the way they should be.
Picture:
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y4hs.png)

Here is my .js and .css file:

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./İlCrud.css";

export default function İlCrud() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  return (
    <div id="il-crud-div">
      <h3>İl CRUD</h3>
      <div id="create-div">
        <input type="text" name="ilKodu" placeholder="İl Kodu..."/>
        <br/>

        <input type="text" name="ilAdi" placeholder="İl Adi..."/>
        <br/>

        <input type="button" id="create" value="Yarat"/>

      </div>
      
      <div id="update-delete-div">
        <input type="button" id="update" value="Güncelle"/>

        <input type="button" id="delete" value="Sil"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here, I have created one container div and created 2 divs inside of it. I have created some buttons and input areas.

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Prosto+One);

*
{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

body
{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Prosto One', cursive;
  background: url('https://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/egg_shell.png');
  _background: #eee;
}

#il-crud-div
{
  color: #777;
  border: 0px solid hsl(0, 0%, 69%);
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 300px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #777;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}

#create-div
{
  color: #777;
  border: 0px solid hsl(0, 0%, 69%);
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #777;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  float: left;
}

#update-delete-div
{
  color: #777;
  border: 0px solid hsl(0, 0%, 69%);
  width: 45%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #777;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  float: left;
}

#create-div input
{
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #afafaf;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  outline: none;
}

#create-div #create
{
  color: white;
  width: 15%;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #0aee62;
}

#update-delete-div #update
{
  color: white;
  width: 15%;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #1501c2;
}

#update-delete-div #delete
{
  color: white;
  width: 15%;
  border: 0px solid transparent;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #d60a0a;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `#create-div input` to `#il-crud-div input` in your css.

Comment: There's no need to stack more than one id selector, since each id can be assigned only once in your document (i.e. `#create-div #create` and `#create` have the same result). If you were expecting to use the same id several times, use classes instead.

Comment: ID's should really only be used for javascript and such and is not recommended for styling. But it's your project and keep at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your css code, you have "#create-div input". Even though you have an id selector on the input 'Button' it's taking on the css code because it's in the id="create-div" and it is an input. You didn't do the same for the update and delete inputs so it's missing the padding and such. Here the sandbox so you can see what I mean https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-kare-jyf76?file=/src/styles.css:1040-1057

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked and I have noticed where I am doing wrong.

Comment: We all go through the same. I'm working on an issue for the last two weeks now, so I know how you feel.

Comment: I really hope you solve the issue you are working on as soon as possible...